# Is there a way using VBA to create a scroll bar and button with links to each, and delete by the press of a button?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on simplifying a worksheet by creating one sheet that has three buttons instead of having three tabs to view.

Here is the workbook.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/Archives.xlsx

What I am attempting to do is this, each button corresponds to a specific tab, it will ultimately adjust each field to fit each corresponding column in each tab. Since Archive 1 needs a different format than Archive 2 or 3.

Now this would be a simple Copy and paste concept, but what I want to have done are two things that makes this a little more complex than a basic script because I can create a script that deletes columns, and pastes data into cells but I will be using a scroll bar, and that can't as far as I can tell be deleted by the same commands or can it? This is what I'm looking for...

<strike>- How to create a scroll bar, with all data corresponding to it so it
   will work with said active data, so if I push the first button all
   data on the screen will correspond to Archive 1, and so will the
   scroll bar. If I push button 2, the data and scroll bar will
   correspond to Archive 2, etc...</strike>

- Have it so that the number of related rows the scroll bar
  interacts with will always correspond to the last row, so there is no
  "empty" data at the end when the scroll bar hits the bottom.
- How to delete said scroll bar as well so it can be replaced by others.

<strike>- This is a want, not a need, but make it so the cells that the data is entered to interact with the scroll bar, and the scroll bar
   will only go so far down as the height of the visible worksheet. So
   in English if the worksheet shows 20 rows, that is how far the bar
   and the data will go.</strike>

Thanks again.

I've decided to try using the lastrow concept to make it so that the script will enter the "lastrow" into the .Max for the scroll bar will go no further than the last row of data, here is the code:

```
    Sub scrollbar()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim wsJAR As Worksheet 'JL Archive
    Dim wsARC As Worksheet 'JL Archive
    Set wsJAR = Sheets("JL Archive")
    Set wsARC = Sheets("Archives")

    With wsARC
    lastrow = wsJAR.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.ScrollBars.Add(1107, 44, 15, 404).Select

        With Selection
            .Max = lastrow
            .LinkedCell = "Lists!$G$3"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

There are no errors, it's accepting lastrow as a number, but in continues past the cell even though there is no reason for it to do so.

The last row is 36, now if I take off 13, from 36 it works perfectly, but I can't imagine that is the answer.

Comment: Yes you can do it. Try recording a macro ;)

Comment: Can do what, create or delete?

Comment: Both ;) Give it a try and if you are stuck, post the code where you are stuck and we will take it from there.

Comment: You know I hear nightmares about using the macro recorder... :p It's amazing with what you learn through this place how much a person can read after going through the school of hard knocks and realize what is garbage and what isn't.

Comment: `You know I hear nightmares about using the macro recorder... :p` I wonder what could they be? You won't believe me but about 60% of the time while coding, I use Macro Recorders! Call me lazy if you want to :)

Comment: Actually I do, because it helps you learn... but I learn by example of good code. I hope you understand :)

Comment: While this might be a good learning exercise, I think you're better off just using different tabs.  They already have their own separate scroll bars, formatting, column widths, etc.  Then what you CAN do with these 3 different tabs is put some navigation buttons at the top, i.e. "Switch to Tab 1", "Switch to Tab 2", etc. (also, kudos for the dropbox link. that helped)

Comment: I'm asking for this for one reason, and one reason only... these archives are attached to a 15 tab workbook. I am attempting to make it into a 5 page workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
With wsARC
    lastrow = wsJAR.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    wsARC.FreezePanes = False
    Range("A1:Q13").Select
    Range("Q1").Activate
    wsARC.FreezePanes = True
End With
```

to

```
With wsARC
    lastrow = wsJAR.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Activate
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    .Range("A1:Q13").Select
    .Range("Q13").Activate
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End With
```

**FINAL CODE**

```
Sub freezecells()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim wsJAR As Worksheet 'JL Archive
    Dim wsARC As Worksheet 'Archive

    Set wsJAR = Sheets("JL Archive")
    Set wsARC = Sheets("Archives")

    With wsARC
        lastrow = wsJAR.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Activate
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False 
        .Range("A1:Q13").Select
        .Range("Q13").Activate
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you mean `.Activate`? That is to make that sheet active so that I can apply `FreezePanes` to it.

Comment: Ok, still getting the same error, same place with the `.FreezePanes` in it.

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? I just tried it and it works perfectly :)

Comment: Check the `FINAL CODE` that I posted above.

Comment: I have, and I copy and pasted... now It is only selecting from A1:F6... not what it should be...

Comment: Same issue. only selecting A1:F6.  I've quit the worksheet and re-opened it.

Comment: Did you refresh the page as I mentioned in my last comment?

Comment: Yup, Calculations are also set to automatic. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/wrap2.xlsm

Comment: You didn't copy the code correctly ;) Do this. Delete the `freezecells()` code from your worksheet and copy it again from above.

Comment: Actually I did. `Sub freezecells()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim wsJAR As Worksheet 'JL Archive
    Dim wsARC As Worksheet 'Archive

    Set wsJAR = Sheets("JL Archive")
    Set wsARC = Sheets("Archives")

    With wsARC
        lastrow = wsJAR.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Activate
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
        .Range("A1:Q13").Select
        .Range("A1").Activate
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    End With
End Sub`

It's still not doing it correctly.

Comment: Here is the sheet with your code: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/wrap3.xlsm

Comment: `.Range("A1").Activate ` Are you sure? ;)

Comment: Yes, because if I did Q13 on **my screen** it shows only rows 7-12 and not the top.

Comment: Is there something still pending beside the screen resolution?

Comment: Yup, but I'm trying to word it correctly to see about getting it fixed.